# Unload event does not fire when redirection happens

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, event-handling

I have an unload event in my page which does not fire when i'm navigating to the next page? is there any option to invoke this event explicitly before navigating to the next page?
I have tried "window.onbeforeunload" but it is displaying a prompt with a message before leaving the current page. I do not want to display the prompt? is there any possibilities to achieve this?

[ASPX]

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" OnUnload="TreeView_Unload">
<Nodes>
<asp:TreeNode Text="Node1" NavigateUrl="http://www.google.com"></asp:TreeNode>
</Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

[C#]
protected void TreeView_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you directing the user to the next page?

If you are using **Response.Redirect(URL, True)** then the response would end at that point and page processing would not be completed (at least, I don't think the unload events would fire).   If you are forcing immediate redirection, then you could try changing your redirect to **Response.Redirect(URL, False)** instead, this would allow your code to finish processing and then redirect the user once completed.

Comment: Hi Stevie,I have specified redirection url in the TreeView node itself. (<asp:TreeNode Text="Node1" NavigateUrl="http://www.google.com"></asp:TreeNode>).So, redirection happens on clicking the node. I want to trigger this unload event before it navigates to the specific page.

Comment: Could you add more code to illustrate what you are doing?  Does the Treeview not create Hyperlinks on the markup that the user clicks to navigate rather than doing a postback?

Comment: if you try the above code you will get the real issue.
Html generated while using the above code:
<div id="MainContent_TreeView1">
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
  <tbody><tr>
   <td><img alt="" src="/102593TreeView/WebResource.axd?d=jQuAGpp91dWAb4kzpNjBe9P3jRN51EfRWLzTzxccd0MuXKd4K80CAsRtnApgmME1ooS3NBbIumQJFUf3ys7ekiIZkvq9t3JS6ZtR3OnR94_VAhmZOKhNHqrp5xUKNhdX0&amp;t=634773918900000000"></td>
<td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a id="MainContent_TreeView1t0" href="http://www.google.com" class="MainContent_TreeView1_0">Node1</a></td>
  </tr></tbody></table>
</div>

Comment: Why would you expect the Unload function to run when the user clicks a link?   The markup you are returning to the user has hyperlinks, so when the user clicks the link there will be no call back to your server, the user will just go to Google.com.   You have said what you are trying to do in the Unload function, however as you should not expect the user to come back to the page, your unload code should run when you are finished creating the page